# Constructor on type not found .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I create.NET Core API then I decide to create Repository so create DataAccessLayer with interfaces and implementations

```
public class GappedData : IGappedData
{
    private readonly GappedContext context;
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, object> repositories;

    public GappedData(GappedContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    public IRepository<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser => this.GetRepository<ApplicationUser>();

    private IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        if (!this.repositories.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            var typeOfRepository = typeof(IRepository<T>);
            var repository = Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfRepository, this.context);

            this.repositories.Add(type, repository);
        }

        return (IRepository<T>)this.repositories[type];
    }
}
```

so when I try to call it throws an exception

> Constructor on type 'Gapped.DataAccessLayer.Interfaces.IRepository`1[[Gapped.Entities.Models.ApplicationUser.ApplicationUser, Gapped.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' not found.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please refrain from posting screenshots of your code but post actual code in text format instead. Also, try to reproduce your problem in a minimal code sample. That is going to make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Can you share code for Startup.cs file? Have you configured the `GappedContext` DbContext there?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood https://gist.github.com/VenimirPetkov/cbb17806f88fc053f41d7072f8db3ab4

Comment: @MohsinMehmood https://gist.github.com/VenimirPetkov/cbb17806f88fc053f41d7072f8db3ab4#file-startup-L45

Comment: @VenimirPetkov Try adding `services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(GappedRepository<>));` inStartup.cs` ConfiguerServices method
`

Comment: @MohsinMehmood it's the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create an instance of an interface here:

```cs
var typeOfRepository = typeof(IRepository<T>);
var repository = Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfRepository, this.context);
```

You are getting that error because interfaces don't have constructors.

Change `typeof(IRepository<T>)` to be `typeof` the concrete implementation instead. (Like `typeof(Repository<T>)` if `Repository<T>` implements the `IRepository<T>` interface.